# Manipulating EC2 instances with mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My goal is to create a game, where a database on a server keeps track of high scores and stores individuals data. I have mysql, and i've set up an EC2 server on aws, and ive linked mysql to my instance on EC2 (using PuTTy) . When I make databases on python using mysql, will this now edit the state of my EC2 instance? And how can I check what data the instance is storing?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Where is your database running? How have you "linked mysql" via PuTTy (which is used for SSH connections)? What is running on the Amazon EC2 instance? Please edit your question to include this information so that we can understand your question better.

Comment: You appear to have asked the same question 3 times ([Linking an EC2 server to a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678241/linking-an-ec2-server-to-a-database), [Python saving feature using SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658307/python-saving-feature-using-sql-database) and this question). StackOverflow is a site for asking specific programming questions, rather than asking for recommendations. I suggest you ask your question at https://www.reddit.com/r/aws, where it is easier to have a 'conversation' with people rather than just seeking an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't ever ask the same question again, **and again**.

> When I make databases on python using mysql, will this now edit the state of my EC2 instance? And how can I check what data the instance is storing?

What you're saying is when you make dB calls with python using MySQL driver how will these dB calls edit the state of the EC2 which you've installed MySQL.

The MySQL database has a database file and the SQL statements run against the database are written/read to the database file. The state of your EC2 won't change much. The Disk will start to fill up and if you're worried about CPU, Disk, Network you can see these stats in the Monitoring Tab in the EC2 dashboard. Hammer your database and see how well your Instance type handles the load.

> how can I check what data the instance is storing?

You use a Database Query Tool like DBeaver or whichever one you [like](https://www.eversql.com/top-7-mysql-gui-tools-for-windows/) to query the database. You can also use your application to query the database using SELECTs.

> I know little to none about SQL databases and the different types, so I apologise if my question may seem not very specific.

Great idea, watch a [FREE video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vsC05rxZ8c) to understand a bit about SQL databases and the different types before asking the same question over and over.